# Kafka consumer receives the message in different format when producer sends as List<Object>

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

```
I am sending `List<Object>` from Kafka Producer to a topic. A consumer which listens to the topic receives the message but in a different format(i.e. `List<LinkedHashMap>` instead of `List<Object>`)

Any idea on how to receive the List<Object> messages in the consumer?I am sending `List<foo>`. But in the Consumer, data comes as `List<LinkedHashMap>`
```

**Just altering the below example as list
        https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-json-serializer-deserializer-example/** From the link you can find the Sender and Listener. Only change is Sender will take Object instead of Foo.

```
public class SpringKafkaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaApplication.class, args);
            }

            @Autowired
            private FooSender sender;

            @Override
            public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
            List<Foo> f = new ArrayList<>();

        f.add(new Foo("Spring Kafka", "sending and receiving JSON messages"))
        f.add(new Foo("Spring Kafka1", "sending and receiving11"))
                sender.send(f);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your consumer code as well?

Comment: @ lloiacono,Just altering the below example as list
    https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-json-serializer-deserializer-example/.  From the link you can find the Sender and Listener. Only change is Sender will take Object instead of Foo. Added spring boot application.            @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        List<Foo> f = new ArrayList<>();
            
    f.add(new Foo("Spring Kafka", "sending and receiving JSON messages"))
    f.add(new Foo("Spring Kafka1", "sending and receiving11"))
            sender.send(f);        }

Answer (score 1):

Don't put code in comments; it's hard to read - edit the question instead.

What version of spring-kafka are you using?

You need at least 2.1.x and a kafka broker >= 0.11 so that type information can be conveyed in headers. [See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/history.html#_json_improvements).

With earlier versions, you have to configure the deserializer with a target type.

**EDIT**

I see the problem; the serializer doesn't know the container (list) content type due to type erasure, and it makes no attempt to introspect the collection to find the type.

While we can probably fix this for simple cases like collections, more complex objects (e.g. maps of maps) would be a challenge.

An array, rather than a list, would probably work.

In the meantime, you can use a message converter instead, where we use the parameter type of the listener to determine the expected type. Here is an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53665459Application2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53665459Application2.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so53665459", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter converter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so53665459", topics = "so53665459")
    public void listen(List<Foo1> foos) {
        System.out.println(foos);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, List<Object>> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so53665459", Collections.singletonList(new Foo1("baz1")));
    }

    public static class Foo1 {

        private String bar;

        public Foo1() {
            super();
        }

        Foo1(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo1 [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
#spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= boot's default StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

and

```
[Foo1 [bar=baz1]]
```

Alternatively, you can subclass the serializer to set up the headers with the proper types, to help the deserializer.

Comment: i am using versions > 2.1 & > 0.11. Still i am getting error

Comment: I see the problem; see the edit to my answer for a couple of work arounds.